# MongoDB saving time as 00:00:00:000Z even if I save new Date()

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

```
return await model.patient.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: data.patientId },
    {
        $set: {
             ...data.therapyStartDate,
            'discipline.$[d].note.$[n].dateOfVisit': myDateVariable
             //more update parts

        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [{ 'd.type': data.disciplineType }, { 'n.status': data.status }]
    });

}
```

A simple update query but still in DB I can see the time as some-date + 00:00:00:000z,

If I console "myDateVariable" it will give me correct date with correct time too and it is a date type too

tried only new Date(), moment and .toISOString() nothing worked

Comment: Try `moment().toDate()`. `new Date()` (not `new date()`) should also work. MongoDB stores date/time values **always** as UTC time

Comment: Yes, I tried them both. Sorry I misspelled new Date() in the question. I guess it is an issue with mongoose, will raise a ticket on their forum today.